# Storage directory in android

Tags: android

I tried using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get a storage root, and making a directory within that:

```
bitmapsDir = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +                  File.separator + "bitmaps");
bitmapsDir.mkdirs();
```

All that executes without exception, and the path is:
`/storage/embedded/0/bitmaps`

When I try to create any file in that directory, I get an `ENOENT/no such file or directory error.`

When I use

```
bitmapsDir = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null) +
                    File.separator + "bitmaps");
```

where "this" is the current activity, it works, and the path is:
`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/belsoft.mirror/files/bitmaps`

Why does trying to use /storage/emulated/0 fail when the other path that is within that path succeeds?

If I use

```
bitmapsDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) +
 File.separator + "bitmaps");
```

the path is `/storage/emulator/0/DCIM/bitmaps` and it fails with ENOENT.

I don't know why these paths are failing, and with no exception on the mkdirs.

I am using Android Studio 2.3.1 on Windows 7, and a Samsung Galaxy Tab 100.

My manifest contains:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: `bitmapsDir.mkdirs();`. Only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet. And check the return value as it might fail to create the directoty. Please adapt your code. Which Android version?

Comment: An app does not need permissions for inside getExternalFilesDir(). Only outside as you have seen.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` returns "mounted."  `mkdirs()` returns false in the failure cases, meaning not created, and the directory did not exist beforehand. The device says Android version 6.0.1.

Comment: `and with no exception on the mkdirs.`. Indeed it just returns a boolean value to indicate if the directory was made. Adapt your code for it.

Comment: But meanwhile you have of course discovered what you forgot for Android 6. As your problem is reported nearly every day here. Just read some pages.

Comment: If greenapps thinks they know the answer, I would appreciate it if they would say straight out what it is.  I have read numerous posts.  I don't think it's a failure to get permissions and I don't think it has to do with using `mkdir` vs. `mkdirs`.    I have also noticed that `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` returns "mounted" even when the SD card is removed.  This seems to me to be a bug in Android - how can it be "mounted" if the device is not there?  Should I report it?  Comments?

Comment: Nothing of your code above has anything to do with a removable SD card. So also not the one for the mounted state.

Comment: mkdirs() cannot create the directory. So it returns false. You stil did not adapt your code for it. If you would have adapted it we could go further. But you keep it up.

Comment: `don't think it's a failure to get permissions`. No it is not. What makes you say so? Nobody suggested that.

Comment: `I don't think it has to do with using mkdir vs. mkdir`. No. Who said it did?

Comment: I meant 'mkdir' vs. 'mkdirs' , a point which has been made in various posts.

Comment: As far as the SD card is concerned - I have tried various things where I have not posted every version of the code.  I am saying that, even though it is not in the version I posted, I did try 'Environment.getExternalStorageState()' and it returned "mounted" even though the card was not physically present, and I am asking if this is not incorrect behavior.

Comment: That function has nothing to do with a removable SD card. I said that before. What did you do more to get the permission?

Comment: According to this article: [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal]

Comment: I will not read an article. Please just answer my question.

Comment: According to this article: [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal] the function `'Environment.getExternalStorageState()` DOES apply to an SD card, if the device has an SD card as external storage, which mine does.  I don't see why you say it has nothing to do with the card.  The article is part of the android docs so it ought to be authoritative.  I now realize that I needed to ask for runtime permissions.  However I think that is a separate question from the system seeming to say that the external storage is mounted when the SD card isn't there.

Comment: It has nothing to do with an SD card. That was before Android 4. And yes you have to ask permission at runtime. That is what you have to do.